# Issues deleting Selected Treeview Item from DB

Tags: python, tkinter

i have my code and there is no error in cmd , i dont know why the selected treeview items dont be deleted from the database , that is my code :

```
    def avsupp():
        global xs
        select = tree.selection()[0]
        xs = tree.get_children(select)

        self.txtdate.delete(0,END)
        self.txtdate.insert(END,xs[1])
        self.txtprix.delete(0,END)
        self.txtprix.insert(END,xs[2])
        self.txtmodele.delete(0,END)
        self.txtmodele.insert(END,xs[3])
        self.txtnoumat.delete(0,END)
        self.txtnoumat.insert(END,xs[4])
        self.txtancmat.delete(0,END)
        self.txtancmat.insert(END,xs[5])
        self.txtNcargr.delete(0,END)
        self.txtNcargr.insert(END,xs[6])
        self.txtnep.delete(0,END)
        self.txtnep.insert(END,xs[7])

    def Supprimer():    
        if (len(prix.get())!=0):
            ded.supp(xs[0])
```

Comment: Where are you calling avsupp function? And what database are you referring to? Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: the database is in another file , you can see that i call it by ded.supp()

Comment: I don't know what `ded` is. Where do you define it?

Comment: ded is the file of database (database functions) like add display and delete (supp).. sql code ,, i define it in the same folder of my file

Comment: and that is my sql code (in ded file) :**def supp():
 connection = sqlite3.connect("immat2.db")
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("DELETE FROM ta WHERE id=?", (id,))
 connection.commit()
 connection.close()**

Comment: Okay, based on the code in the question, though, those details would be useful... Please [edit] your post to include more details

Comment: You could also attempt to debug your code by adding print statements where you think actions should be occurring since we're not able to run what you've posted without a [mcve]